# Ways to create Objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object, backbone.js

looking at the annotated source of Backbone.js found that they have a peculiar way to create some Objects that I havent seen before.

```
(MyObject = {});
```

And they use it for example in the sync function like this:

```
MyObject || (MyObject = {})['foo'] = bar;
```

Was wondering why the create or interact with Objects in this way and what benefits this bring at the development process?

This first idea comes to my mind is that is a function that return the object passed as a parameter but don't understand why not to do:

```
Myobject = MyObject || {};
```

**Example of  Backbone use**

```
(attrs = {})[key] = val;
```

Comment: Are you sure those are the grouping parentheses you intended? Did you mean `(MyObject || MyObject = {})['foo'] = bar;`?

Comment: Assignment returns the value that is assigned. The return value of `MyObject = {}` is the `{}` that was assigned to `MyObject`. Assuming @Matt's guess is correct, the code is assigning a new object to `MyObject` if it is falsy (which weakly implies that `MyObject` is undefined or null), then assigning `bar` to the `"foo"` key of `MyObject`.

Comment: Hello guys, added an example of Backbone anotated source :) Thank you for your replies

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez Yes, similar principle in that snippet. The variable `attrs` is assigned an empty object, and since assignment returns the assigned value, the parenthesized expression evaluates to the `{}` that was just assigned to `attr`. Then you assign `val` to the `key` property of this object. The net result is equivalent to `attr = {}; attr[key]=val;`.